# PassKit - Reading a Wallet boarding pass from iOS application

Tags: ios, swift, wallet

I am trying to extract train boarding pass data stored in Wallet through PassKit API from a Swift app.

I read the whole documentation, it only explains how to create custom passes, modify on delete them.
What I want is to parse all train boarding passes, and extract departure, arrival, times ... informations from it.
Is it possible to do so ?

If not I read about alternative solutions scanning QRCodes information, is it feasible to scan them with this method ? Or is there any alternative option ?

Comment: Do you own the passes that you are trying to read?  You can only access passes that are signed with a certificate issued to your team.

Comment: No, I would like to read train boarding passes with user authorisation. So I guess it is not possible ...